# NPM location in ASP.Net 5 application

Tags: npm, asp.net-core, package.json

I am creating an ASP.Net 5 application and have a few npm packages that are needed by the client.  I have package.json configured and I see the NPM folder under dependencies.  I also see the hidden node_modules folder with the actual packages.

These files can't be served because the are not in the wwwroot folder.

I tried adding package.json to the wwwroot folder and that adds the packages to wwwroot.  However, I get an error that I think is related to paths that are too long.  It get: "the item metadata (fullpath) cannot be applied node_modules".  In addition, most examples show package.json at the root level.

I have seen examples of the gulp file that minifies the packages.  It seems to expect the packages to be in wwwroot but that is not where they are by default.

I have found a way to move bower packages to wwwroot but I can't use bower for some of these packages.

What's the best practice for this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any best practice for this but the *common* practice is what you've described. This is a little bit different for aspnet5 projects however.

The aspnet5 team assumes the you pull down `npm` packages to be used with `gulp`. `bower` on the other hand *should* be used to pull down frontend dependencies.

> I have seen examples of the gulp file that minifies the packages. It
>   seems to expect the packages to be in wwwroot but that is not where
>   they are by default.

The default scaffolding should have a minify task. Take a look at your `gulpfile.js`. In that file, there's a `paths.webroot` that is by default `./wwwroot`. The `min:js` task will find all your javascript files in the `/wwwroot/js` folder, concatenate and minify it. If you need to add more `gulp` tasks, then you just chain them up in that task. If your scripts are in the `/wwwroot/js` folder, then there is no need to fiddle with the paths.

Comment: How do NPM packages get into wwwroot?

Comment: @user1617407 They don't. They go in the `node_modules` folder. `bower` packages go into `/wwwroot/lib` folder by default.

Comment: So how can my browser call them?  I am specifically trying to work with the angular2 beta tutorial which is npm based, not bower.

Comment: Have you tried the bower [angular2](https://libraries.io/bower/angular2) package?

Comment: Yes.  But what installs is really angular, not angular2.

Comment: Oh sorry yep that checks out. I think the only way forward is to use `npm3` as [angular2 will not support bower](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4018) and probably partly because [bower is dying](https://github.com/bower/bower/pull/1748#issuecomment-150104311). There's an [issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/1074) about that in the aspnet repo as well. For now, I guess you could copy the scripts you need manually in the `wwwroot` folder or install `npm3` and add a `package.json` inside the `wwwroot` folder?

Comment: That's what I am doing.  It seems convoluted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use gulp to move the dependencies you need. Here is an example of copying jquery from `node_modules` to `wwwroot`.

```
gulp.task("jquery",
    function() {
        return gulp.src("node_modules/jquery/dist/*")
                   .pipe(gulp.dest("wwwroot/lib/jquery"));
});
```